# Scroll and table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="main" style="max-width: 65px !important; overflow: scroll">
   <table border="1">
       <tr><td>a</td><td>s</td><td>d</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td><td>l</td></tr>    
   </table>
​</div>​

​td {
   padding: 15px;
}​


​$('#main').scroll(function(){
    console.log($(this).scrollLeft());
    //console.log( current TD on left );
})​​​​​
```

How can i show current element on left in this table? For start should be **a**, and next if TD with **s** is on left inside this table then should show me **s**

http://jsfiddle.net/8KLDc/

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question. Could you rephrase/explain  that last paragraph? What do you mean by current element, and what is it that you are trying to do? Maybe some extra context would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#main').scroll(function() {

    offset = $(this).offset();

    currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(offset.left + 20, offset.top);

    console.log(currentElement.innerHTML);
})​;​
```

First, it finds the position of the `#main` element on the page. It then searches for the element that is 20px to the right of that location (since we want the cell that is closest to the centre).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/8KLDc/2/